# creating list of strings in R

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a list v

```
> v[1:5]
[1] A1CF    A2M     A2M     AADAC   AADACL3
```

If I attempt to create a new list

```
x=c(v[1],v[2])
```

I get

```
> x
[1] 1 2
```

Why does R assign integer values to x, and how can I assign strings to the new list x?

Comment: It seems that `v` is a vector of factors. Try `factor(c(levels(v)[1], levels(v)[2]))` or equivalently `factor(levels(v)[1:2])`. Can you provide the output of `dput(v)`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `v` is a vector of factors.

```
> v <- factor(c("A1CF", "A2M", "A2M", "AADAC", "AADACL3"))
> c(v[1],v[2])  # this reproduces your problem  
[1] 1 2
> 
> # possible alternatives. This solves your problem
> factor(c(levels(v)[1], levels(v)[2])) # Alternative 1
[1] A1CF A2M 
Levels: A1CF A2M
> factor(levels(v)[1:2])                # Alternative 2
[1] A1CF A2M 
Levels: A1CF A2M
```

Btw, you are dealing with a vector, not with a list.

Comment: or just `as.character`, no?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta. Yes, it could be possible, but the OP didn't explain good enough what he/she wants as result.